# Update Primary Email address

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to update primary email address of all distribution groups in AD.

E.g. Currently all groups have proxy address field set to SMTP:abc@contoso.com; smtp:abc@contoso2.com => So contoso is primary and contoso2 is secondary. (NOTE: For some groups there could multiple email addresses set to secondary e.g. SMTP:abc@contoso.com; smtp:abc@contoso2.com; smtp:abc@contoso3.com; smtp:abc@contoso4.com)

I would like to change it to smtp:abc@contoso.com; SMTP:abc@contoso2.com =>have contoso2 as primary and contoso as secondary. (leave contoso3, contoso4 etc as secondary)

Can someone please advise, how can I do it via PowerShell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this to change the primary email address on every distribution group:

```
# this is the email domain part that should become the primary address for every distribution group
$newPrimaryEmailDomain = 'contoso2.com'

Get-ADGroup -Filter "groupcategory -eq 'distribution'" -Properties * |
    Select-Object Name, Mail, proxyAddresses, DistinguishedName | ForEach-Object {
        $group = $_
        # get the current primary email address and remove the 'SMTP:' prefix
        $oldPrimaryAddress = ($group.ProxyAddresses | Where-Object { $_ -cmatch '^SMTP:.*' }) -replace '^SMTP:', ''
        # split the current primary address
        $emailName, $emailDomain = $oldPrimaryAddress -split '@'
        if ($newPrimaryEmailDomain -eq $emailDomain) {
            Write-Host "Group '$($group.Name)' already has the correct primary email address ($oldPrimaryAddress)"
            continue
        }

        # create the new primary email address
        $newPrimaryAddress = 'SMTP:{0}@{1}' -f $emailName, $newPrimaryEmailDomain
        # add the lowercase 'smtp:' prefix to the old address to make it secondary
        $oldPrimaryAddress = 'smtp:' + $oldPrimaryAddress

        # read all other existing addresses, excluding the old primary address and the new one should it be in the list as secondary address
        $otherAddresses = @($group.ProxyAddresses | Where-Object { ($_ -cnotmatch '^SMTP:.*') -and ($_ -ne $newPrimaryAddress)})
        # add the old primary address to the 'other' (secondary) addresses and remove any duplicates
        $otherAddresses = ($otherAddresses + $oldPrimaryAddress) | Sort-Object -Unique
        # recreate the complete proxy addresses array with the new Primary address on top
        $newProxyAddresses = @($newPrimaryAddress) + $otherAddresses

        # finally replace the group proxy addresses.:
        Set-ADGroup -Identity $group.DistinguishedName -Clear ProxyAddresses
        Set-ADGroup -Identity $group.DistinguishedName -Add @{'proxyAddresses'=$newProxyAddresses }
        Write-Host "Group '$($group.Name)' new primary email address: $($newPrimaryAddress -replace '^SMTP:', '')" -ForegroundColor Green
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Theo. This looks much cleaner way to do it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I can use the following script. Though its not great, and I am taking advantage of the fact that we can't add duplicates in proxyAddresses field

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter 'groupcategory -eq "distribution"' -SearchBase "OU=Test Groups,DC=test,DC=local" -Properties * |
    select Name,mail,@{Name=’proxyAddresses’;Expression={$_.proxyAddresses -join ";"}} |
    Export-Csv "C:\temp\Distribution-Group-Members.csv" -NoTypeInformation

#Create new CSV file ,  update email column with beteast, add new column as "proxy" and add proxymailaddresses 
Import-Csv -Path 'C:\temp\Distribution-Group-Members.csv' |
    Select-Object -Property Name, @{Label='proxyAddresses'; Expression={"SMTP:$($_.Mail);$($_.proxyAddresses -replace 'SMTP', 'smtp')"}} |
    Export-Csv 'C:\temp\Distribution-Group-Members-updated.csv' -NoTypeInformation

#Update all DLs with correct email address and proxy email addresses 
Import-Csv "c:\temp\Distribution-Group-Members-Updated.csv" | Foreach {
    Get-ADGroup $_.Name |
        Set-ADGroup -add @{proxyaddresses=($_.proxyAddresses -split ";")}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory 
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase 'DC=test,DC=net' -prop mail |
ForEach-Object { 
    Set-ADUser -Identity $_  -EmailAddress ($_.mail -replace "@abc.com","@123.com")
}
```

Comment: This doesn't actually work. Primary and secondary email addresses are stored in multi-value `proxyaddresses` attribute.